# How to allow & in between a word in url with Spanish characters without url encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I Had sped lots of time to resolve a issue. I am Calling a 3rd party API like

[http://abc/app.aspx?deFleetLastName=MyName&Test123&deFleetFirstName=ààÃÅjeetaSisodiààÃÅ](http://abc/app.aspx?deFleetLastName=MyName&Test123&deFleetFirstName=%C3%A0%C3%A0%C3%83%C3%85jeetaSisodi%C3%A0%C3%A0%C3%83%C3%85)

In above url I want to allow & between a word like MyName&Test123.
Also I want to allow Spanish characters like ààÃÅjeetaSisodiààÃÅ

I am using below code to allow Spanish characters and its working fine.

```
AuthRequest = "&deTCIVRAccountNumber=" + SecCardReq.AdminNumber;
                AuthRequest += "&deCISSTitle=" + SecCardReq.Title;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardHolderIdentFirstName=" + SecCardReq.FirstName;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardHolderIdentMiddleName=" + SecCardReq.MiddleName;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardHolderIdentLastName=" + SecCardReq.LastName;
                AuthRequest += "&deCISSSecLastName=" + SecCardReq.SecLastName;
                AuthRequest += "&deCISSNameOnCard=" + SecCardReq.NameOnCard;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardHolderIdentAddressLine1=" + SecCardReq.AddressLine1;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardHolderIdentAddressLine2=" + SecCardReq.AddressLine2;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardRegistrationCity=" + SecCardReq.City;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardHolderIdentificationStateProvince=" + SecCardReq.State;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardRegistrationPostalCode=" + SecCardReq.PostalCode;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardRegistrationCountry=" + SecCardReq.Country;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardRegistrationEmail=" + SecCardReq.Email;
                AuthRequest += "&deCISSEmail2=" + SecCardReq.Email2;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardHolderIdentDOB=" + SecCardReq.DOB;
                AuthRequest += "&deCISSMotherMaidenName=" + SecCardReq.MotherMaidenName;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardHolderIdentificationIdCode=" + SecCardReq.IdType;
                AuthRequest += "&deCIAOtherIDDescription=" + SecCardReq.IDDescription;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardHolderIdentificationIdNumber=" + SecCardReq.IdNumber;
                AuthRequest += "&deCIAIDIssueDate=" + Convert.ToString(SecCardReq.IDIssueDate);
                AuthRequest += "&deCIAIDExpirationDate=" + Convert.ToString(SecCardReq.IDExpirationDate);

                AuthRequest += "&deCIASIssuedBy=" + SecCardReq.IDIssuedBy;
                AuthRequest += "&deCIAIDIssueState=" + SecCardReq.IDIssueState;
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryCardTypeForAPI=" + SecCardReq.SecondaryCardTypeForAPI;
                AuthRequest += "&deCIASHomePhoneCCode=" + SecCardReq.HomePhoneCountryCode;
                AuthRequest += "&deTCIVRCardRegistrationPhone=" + SecCardReq.HomePhoneNumber;
                AuthRequest += "&deCIASOfficePhoneCCode=" + SecCardReq.WorkPhoneCountryCode;
                AuthRequest += "&deCISSWorkPhoneNumber=" + SecCardReq.WorkPhoneNumber;
                AuthRequest += "&deCIASOfficePhoneExt=" + SecCardReq.WorkPhoneExt;
                AuthRequest += "&deMobilePhCCode=" + SecCardReq.MobilePhoneNumberCCode;
                AuthRequest += "&deCISSMobilePhoneNumber=" + SecCardReq.MobilePhoneNumber;
                AuthRequest += "&deFaxNumberCCode=" + SecCardReq.HomeFaxNumberCCode;
                AuthRequest += "&deCISSHomeFaxNumber=" + SecCardReq.HomeFaxNumber;
                AuthRequest += "&deWorkFaxNumberCCode=" + SecCardReq.WorkFaxNumberCCode;
                AuthRequest += "&deCISSWorkFaxNumber=" + SecCardReq.WorkFaxNumber;
                AuthRequest += "&deCISSLanguageIndicator=" + SecCardReq.LanguageIndicator;
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryCardPinAPI=" + SecCardReq.SecondaryCardPin;
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryCardDealerNumberForAPI=" + SecCardReq.SecondaryCardDealerNumber;
                AuthRequest += "&deIVREmbossingHotStamp=" + SecCardReq.EmbossingHotStamp;
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryCardPrivacy=" + SecCardReq.SecondaryCardPrivacy;
                AuthRequest += "&dePPCIPNumber=" + SecCardReq.PPCIPNumber;
                AuthRequest += "&deIVREmbossingLine4=" + SecCardReq.EmbossingLine4;
                AuthRequest += "&dePPCIPType=" + SecCardReq.PPCIPType;
                AuthRequest += "&dePDDeliveryMechanism=" + SecCardReq.DeliveryMechanism;
                AuthRequest += "&dePPCIPStatus=" + SecCardReq.PPCIPStatus;
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryCardExpOptForAPI=" + (SecCardReq.SecondaryCardExpOpt != null ? SecCardReq.SecondaryCardExpOpt : "");
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryVCExpAfrTxnEntryAPI=" + SecCardReq.SecondaryVCExpAfrTxnEntry ?? "";
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryVCExprAfrDaysEntryAPI=" + SecCardReq.SecondaryVCExprAfrDaysEntry ?? "";
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryVCExprAfrDaysEntryDuration=" + SecCardReq.SecondaryVCExprAfrDaysEntryDuration ?? "";
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryVCExpOnDate=" + (SecCardReq.SecondaryVCExpOnDate != null ? SecCardReq.SecondaryVCExpOnDate : "");
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryVirtualCardLimit=" + SecCardReq.SecondaryVirtualCardLimit;
                AuthRequest += "&deSecondaryVirtualCardResetAllowedForAPI=" + "0"; // As per new changes in SCP
                AuthRequest += "&deCardValidFromDateAPI=" + SecCardReq.StartDate; // As per new changes in SCP
                AuthRequest += "&deCardValidTillDateAPI=" + SecCardReq.StopDate; // As per new changes in SCP
                AuthRequest += "&deBookingRefNumber=" + SecCardReq.BookingRefNumber; // As per new changes in SCP
                AuthRequest += "&dePPSSN=" + SecCardReq.DecryptedSSN;
                AuthRequest += "&deIVRSource=" + PortalCommon.PlateFormName;
                AuthRequest += "&deMakerCheckerJobID=" + SecCardReq.jobID;
                AuthRequest += "&deMakerCheckerFlag=" + SecCardReq.makerCheckerFlag;

                AuthRequest += "&deExistingCustomerId=" + SecCardReq.CustomerId;
                AuthRequest += "&deBankingCustomerIdAPI=" + SecCardReq.BankingCustomerId;

                //IDS CIBANCO CHANGES
                AuthRequest += "&dePoBCountry=" + SecCardReq.POBCountry;
                AuthRequest += "&dePoBState=" + SecCardReq.POBStateProvince;
                AuthRequest += "&dePoBCity=" + SecCardReq.POBCity;
                AuthRequest += "&deNationality=" + SecCardReq.Nationality;
                AuthRequest += "&deSACCode=" + SecCardReq.SACActivationCode;
                AuthRequest += "&deCHCustomerIdDetailMsg=" + SecCardReq.IDDetails;

                HttpRequestMsg = "User=" + (Convert.ToString(UserLogin));
                HttpRequestMsg += "&Password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToString(UserPassword));
                HttpRequestMsg += "&Application=appCardinal";
                HttpRequestMsg += "&dbbServiceName=svcIVRSecondaryCard";
                HttpRequestMsg += "&dbbSystemExtLogin=1";
                HttpRequestMsg += "&deDBBServiceApiLevel=1.2";


 HttpRequestMsg += AuthRequest;
                HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BaseUrl);
                httpRequest.Method = "POST"; httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-Forwarded-For", objLoginUserInfo.HostIp); httpRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", AddAuthorizationHeader());
                httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                httpRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

                string sOutput = string.Empty;
                sOutput = CommonBLL.GetDBBIDServiceResponse(httpRequest, HttpRequestMsg);



   public static string GetDBBIDServiceResponse(HttpWebRequest httpRequest, string httpRequestMsg)
    {
        string responseString = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            Utilities.APITraceEnable(httpRequestMsg);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(httpRequestMsg);
            httpRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream newStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
            newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
            newStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CreateLogFile.CreateActivityLog("CommonBLL GetEncodingWindows1252 Exception =============== " + ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return responseString;
    }
```

Problem occurs when user enter & char.
To allow & we can use HttpUtility.UrlEncode , but I don't want to use HttpUtility.Urlencode

Please suggest me how can allow & and Spanish characters in above API calling

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use HttpUtility.Urlencode?

Comment: @Seano666 yes  because HttpUtility.Urlencode Encode Spanish character too.

Comment: More like a workaround than a solution, however maybe you could replace "&" with " and " ?

Comment: @Ignas wouldnt work. The api call can't distinguish things like that. When you do an api pull the variables in the url are used to query through the api. If you replaced "&" with "and" it would become a different query. The problem is, & is used to attatch an additional variable to the api query normally ie "firstname=bob&lastname=smith"

Comment: Any reason not to encode spanish characters. As per http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2 URI should be ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

You can use %26 to replace the & symbol within your query variables. It counts as the same (a bit like how %20 is the equivalent to a space). Parse your variables and replace the & with the above code and you should be set.

For example, you could write `MyName%26Test123` which would be the same as `MyName&Test123`

See http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php as a reference to the different codes used to replace characters

**Update**

Based on what I can see from your API construction, you can sort this out pretty easily. All your data is stored in a single class, so cycle through each property using the following

```
public void ParseAmpersand()
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(string)
        {
            ((string)pi.GetValue(this)).Replace("&", "%26");
        }
    }               
}
```

This will cycle through all properties in that object that are of type `string` and replace the & with the %26 code. All you need to do is place this into the class you already created (`SecCardReq`) and call it before you build your API string.

Comment: thanks for your response. I already tried this solution and its working fine, problem is we have thousands of textboxes in our project.

Comment: I don't  want to reach every control.

Comment: @Jaihind can you explain in a little more detail? Your question suggests you only need to to replace it in variables being sent to the API call. Therefore, parse the variables being submitted, not the textbox values

Comment: Yes I want to replace it in API call. I have multiple API with multiple parameters, so at this time its not possible to replace special characters in every parameters of each API. I am looking for a solution that need minimum efforts

Comment: @Jaihind I genuinly think there is no real way to do that. At the very least you need to parse every variable string before it goes through. Sadly, you have committed a faux pas of sorts by allowing a reserved symbol to be passed to the URL. Im afraid you are stuck with having to do things the long way.

Comment: It might be worth you updating your question with an example showing how you construct one of your api calls (as in what constructs the `httpRequestMsg` string)

Comment: Please give a look I update my question, how I construct my request to call an API